# Possible bug in Math.round(decimal)

Tags: apex, math

I have written this code and run anonymously, and got some strange results which seem to indicate a bug in `Math.Round(decimal)` - look like an overflow:

```
Decimal d  = 1000000000.0;
Decimal dd = 10000000000.0;
Decimal ddd = 100000000000000.0;
System.debug('d='+d);
System.debug('dd='+dd);
System.debug('ddd='+ddd);

System.debug('round d='+Math.round(d));
System.debug('round dd='+Math.round(dd));
System.debug('round ddd='+Math.round(ddd));
```

Results are:

```
d=1000000000.0
dd=10000000000.0
ddd=100000000000000.0

round d=1000000000
round dd=1410065408
round ddd=276447232
```

As you see, it's wrong from dd `onwards`.

Is this definitely a bug, or am I misunderstanding something?
If it is a bug, has anyone else found this? Is there a workaround?

Comment: In line 6, you have `System.debug('dd=')` but in your results you have `ddd=` FYI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Math.roundToLong instead, as Math.round returns an Integer

```
Decimal d  = 1000000000.0;
Decimal dd = 10000000000.0;
Decimal ddd = 100000000000000.0;
System.debug('d='+d);
System.debug('dd='+dd);
System.debug('ddd='+ddd);

System.debug('round d='+Math.roundToLong(d));
System.debug('round dd='+Math.roundToLong(dd));
System.debug('round ddd='+Math.roundToLong(ddd));
```

This gives the results you would expect

```
d=1000000000.0
dd=10000000000.0
ddd=100000000000000.0

round d=1000000000
round dd=10000000000
round ddd=100000000000000
```

Answer (score 5):

This isn't well defined behavior. `Math.round` returns an `Integer`, which has a [maximum value of 2147483647](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex3_4.htm). `dd` and `ddd` both exceed this cap - this, along with the fact that Decimal has no explicit upper bound, speaks to this behavior.

If you try this, with a Double that **does** have an explicit upper bound of (2^63) - 1, a MathException for Integer overflow is thrown, as expected:

```
Double dbl = 100000000000000.0;
System.debug(Math.round(dbl));
```

> System.MathException: Integer overflow: 100000000000000